# how to make each grid with different color

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I'm trying to make each grid with different color the value is coming from the controller (from api)

I cant reach every grid because using the map doesn't provide an index for each grid.

is there another way to view these grids or another way to color each one with different color?

here is the code :

```dart
                        GridView.count(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            childAspectRatio: getProportionateScreenWidth(159) /
                                getProportionateScreenWidth(115),
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: getProportionateScreenWidth(28.5),
                            mainAxisSpacing: getProportionateScreenWidth(14.3),
                            children: controller.letters.map(
                              (e) {
                                counter++;
                                return Material(
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                      getProportionateScreenWidth(33)),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: getProportionateScreenWidth(115),
                                    width: getProportionateScreenWidth(159),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          getProportionateScreenWidth(33)),
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                      e,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize:
                                              getProportionateScreenWidth(54),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: counter % 2 == 0
                                              ? Color(0xff6FC989):
                                             Color(0xff00A49A)
                                      )
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          ),
```

What I want to view is like this

[image]

Comment: [mapIndexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListExtensions/mapIndexed.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the `List` of `Color` before and then modify your code a little (convert your `controller.letters` to `Map`:

```dart
children: controller.letters.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
  return Material(
    child: Contaner(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(entry.value), // value contains you `letter`.
        style: TextStyle(
          color: _generatedColors[entry.key], // key containes index starting from 0.
        ),    
      ),
    ),
  );  
}).toList();
```